# Sorting Array of References

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, linked-list

I'm trying to sort an array of references of linked list using quicksort, here's the code for quicksort. This isn't working, so can someone help me with the error.

```
public static int partition(linkedList arr[], int left, int right){
    int i = left, j = right;
    linkedList tmp;
    linkedList pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

    while (i <= j){
        while (arr[i] < (pivot)) //getting error bad operand types
            i++;

        while (arr[j] > (pivot)) //getting error bad operand types
            j--;

        if (i <= j){
            tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    };

    return i;
}   

public static void quickSort(linkedList arr[], int left, int right){
    int index = partition(arr, left, right);
    if (left < index-1)
        quickSort(arr, left, index-1);

    if (index < right)
        quickSort(arr, index, right);

}
```

Comment: Is {"apple", "orange"} smaller or bigger than {"plane", "car"}? Nobody knows. You can't compare references with `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 1):

> the linked lists contains strings so I would need to **compare the first
>   element of each linked** to see if its greater or less, but i can't
>   figure this out

maybe you want this?

```
Assume 
- you declared your linkedlist with generic like new LinkedList<String>()
- no null value in lists

     while (arr[i].get(0).compareTo( pivot.get(0))<=0)
... 
     while (arr[j].get(0).compareTo( pivot.get(0))>0)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the operators `<` and `>` defined for the `linkedList` objects? This is the cause of the error.

You can overcome this by simply replacing the `<` and `>` by some comparison functions. Write the functions yourself. The function should take two `linkedList` objects as parameters and do the comparison, then return a value representing the results of comparison.

This can be something like this:

```
int compare(linkedList list1, linkedList list2)
{
    if(list1.get(0) < list2.get(0)) return -1;
    if(list1.get(0) > list2.get(0)) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Then simply call this function in `partition()` and make the decision over the value returned from `compare()`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `LinkedList` not `linkedList`, but I suppose the problem is not here.

The other problem is with: `arr[i] < (pivot)`. You are comparing instances of `Object` to each other. You cannot do that.

From which type is your objects? You should define the type explicitly like `LinkedList<Integer>` and then you can write something like `arr.get(i).compareTo(pivot) < 0`

Comment: the linked lists contains strings so I would need to compare the first element of each linked to see if its greater or less, but i can't figure this out

Comment: I don't get it. you have array of linked lists of strings? because your condition arr[i] < (pivot) is comparing a linked list to a linked list!

Comment: I have an array, which contains references to linked lists. The linked lists themselves are strings. so if want to compare linkedlist 1 with linkedlist 2, i can compare the first string from each to see which one is greater/less than alphabetically? for eg. cat < dog

Comment: LinkedList does not implement Comparable, which means you can not write something like list1.compareTo(list2).
Kent's solution would work in your case